# How does HasManyThrough differ from MappedManyToMany?

Tags: scala, lift, mapper

Most of the [lift-mapper documentation](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/Mapper#manytomany) on many-to-many relationships documents the use of [MappedManyToMany](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.2/framework/scaladocs/net/liftweb/mapper/ManyToMany.MappedManyToMany.html) for mapping the relationship.  But in in [Exploring Lift](http://exploring.liftweb.net/master/index-8.html#toc-Subsection-8.1.4), I see that the authors use [HasManyThrough](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.2/framework/scaladocs/net/liftweb/mapper/HasManyThrough.html) instead.

What's the difference between the two?  Is one preferred over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HasManyThrough`

- only gives you read support
- you will have to call `get` on it to get the elements
- you need to create the join table entries manually

`MappedManyToMany`

- also handles writes
- can be used like a collection (for example add and remove objects with `+=` and `-=`)
- join table entries will be created automatically

At least these are the differences I noticed when moving from `HasManyThrough` to `MappedManyToMany` in my project.

So I think `MappedManyToMany` is a new version and is the preferred one, while `HasManyThrough` is propably kept for compatibility reasons.